# Does C# use the -> pointer notation?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, struct

I am trying to learn C# and I am familiar with the C++ struct pointing notation `->`. I was curious if that crossed over into C#.

Example:

```
someStruct->someAttribute += 1;
```

Comment: This should probably be on stackoverflow.

Comment: I've never seen more massively upvoted, massively wrong, answers on a Programmers.SE question!

Comment: @Billy, if the answers given below are wrong, I'm sure we'd all appreciate if you came up with a right answer.

Comment: @Kristian: I downvoted the wrong ones and upvoted the right ones. Some of them are right -- all the answers saying "C# does not have pointers" or "C# does not expose pointers to the user" are 110% wrong. (Really Macke's is the only right answer)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is pointer notation in C#, but only in special cases, using the `unsafe` keyword.

Regular objects are dereferenced using `.`, but if you want to write fast code, you can pin data (to avoid the garbage collector moving stuff around) and thus "safely" use pointer arithmetic, and then you might need `->`.

See [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=VS.100).aspx) and a bit down in [this example](http://www.codersource.net/microsoft-net/c-advanced/c-unsafe-code.aspx) on the use of `->` in C#.

It looks something like this (from the last link):

```
struct MyStruct 
{ 
    public long X; 
    public double D; 
}

unsafe static void foo() 
{
   var myStruct = new MyStruct(); 
   var pMyStruct = & myStruct;

   // access:

   (*pMyStruct).X = 18; 
   (*pMyStruct).D = 163.26;

   // or

   pMyStruct->X = 18; 
   pMyStruct->D = 163.26;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: `(*a).b` is equivalent to `a->b` in both C# and C++.

Comment: The one thing I'd add to that is that you could easily spend years as a C# developer, working in the domains that C# is frequently used for, and never once have any reason to use `unsafe` code or a pointer. I never have.

Comment: @Carson63000: Yeah. `unsafe` is probably only needed if you feel that you should rewrite a small algorithm in C++ or C. In those cases, writing the code using unsafe at first might be better than the hassle of writing/integrating/shipping a piece of native code with your app.

Comment: Also, nice about the many upvotes. I'm a C++ guy most of the time. Should learn more C# to get more rep, as I never get that many upvotes on my C++ answers. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't differentiate between pointers and references. In effect everything is a reference so uses the . notation.

Edit: as is pointed out in the comments below it's not as simple as that. There are reference types and value types. What I meant above is that there is no distinction between reference types and pointer types.

Edit2: Although apparently there is if you're using the unsafe parts of c#! I've learnt something today!

Comment: Not everything in C# is a reference. Variables of primitive types such as `int` are not references, and types declared with `struct` are not references.

Comment: C# does differentiate between pointers and references, and you can use pointers in an unsafe context: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that C# decided to use `.` rather than `->` to reference a member of an object referred to by a class reference, since the semantics are closer to those of C's `->` operator than its `.` operator.  For example, in C, if one sees the code `a=b; a.X=5;` one would recognize that it's writing to field `X` of some struct `a`, which is a different struct from `b`.  By contrast, if one sees the code `a=b; a->X=5;` one would recognize that it's writing to field `X` of the struct pointed to by *both* `a` and `b`.  In C#, the behavior of the code in question would depend upon whether the type of `b` is a class or a struct.

The addition of generics to C#, however, would have been difficult if C# had used different dereferencing operators for class and struct types, since it's possible for a particular piece of code to dereference an instance of an interface- constrained type without knowing whether the type in question is a struct or a class; it's unclear which operator should be used if structs used a different operator from classes.

Answer (score -4):

While C# has pointers behind the scenes they are totally hidden from the user.  You can't get at a pointer to dereference it.  You only have the dot notation to access something inside something, whether the original is a pointer or not is hidden from you.

The only way you are even aware of pointers is things that pass by reference rather than passing by value.

Comment: (1) `unsafe` code *has* pointers. (2) C# does not, by default, pass by reference (although, unlike Java where this myth is even more prelevant, it *can* if the programmer asks for it) - that would mean `void f(T x) { x = ...; }` would change the caller's variable `x` if called as `f(x)`. Most things are a references, yes. But those references are passed by value. You can mutate what's behind those references (object members, for instance), but that's not what "pass by reference" means.