# '->' operator in C#, what does it do?

Tags: c#

I've been looking into the source code of an audio recorder and I noticed that the code has used the `->` operator in the code a lot. For example:

```
WaveInHeaders[i]->dwUser = IntPtr.Zero;
WaveInHeaders[i]->lpNext = IntPtr.Zero;
WaveInHeaders[i]->reserved = IntPtr.Zero;
```

I have never seen anything like that in C# before, it reminds me of the C++ iterator, but I just wanna make it clear to myself. What is that and what does it do? (it was used in an unsafe class)

Comment: Since this is an `unsafe` code, then `->` is derefence. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405212/does-c-sharp-use-the-pointer-notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a field access operator. It allows you to access a field of a structure through a pointer to that structure in unmanaged code. All operators allowed on pointers are described in [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx).

In this case `WaveInHeaders` is an array of pointers to structures. Each structure has (at least) three fields of type [`IntPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IntPtr(v=vs.110).aspx) - `dwUser`, `lpNext`, and `reserved`.

Comment: So considering the fact that Structs are immutable in C#, that is the reason why the author of the code is using pointers that way, is that right? But what's wrong with using a class??

Comment: Who said structs are immutable in C#? It's better practice to design your structs to be immutable, and the built-in primitive value types do follow this practice, but you can certainly build mutable structs in C#, too.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: But are they naturally mutable as a default behavior?

Comment: @Arrrr - here's a mutable struct: `public struct Foo { public string Name { get; set; } }`. That's the default behaviour.

Comment: @Arrrr Yes, there are. The built-in primitive value types are not, but your own structs are, unless you carefully design them not to be.

Comment: @Arrrr `struct`s are not immutable (although it's definitely a good idea to make them immutable). That is not the reason why the code is using pointers, though: it appears that the authors of the code do not want to put `struct`s themselves into an array, perhaps because these structures belong to some other places in non-contiguous memory.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Maybe I get it upside down, but imagine you pass a struct to a list, the values can never be change. In VS 2015 the intellisense even prevents it in compile time.

Comment: @Arrrr That's different from immutability, though: the thing with structures in containers is that when a `struct` is returned from the `[]` operator, it's returned by value, which is another way of saying that a copy is returned. That is why you get the error in VS 2015 when you try modifying a `struct` in a container. If you do the same thing in an array, though, there would not be an error, and the code would do what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator is used for accessing an object's interface via pointers.